# Issue facing with push notification

Tags: php, ios

I have a problem with push notification in my app. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) as an example of programming push notifications. When I run:

```
php simplepush.php
```

on the server, every time I get "message is successfully delivered", but only some of the devices get the notifications.

Comment: which environment you set `Sandbox|Production`?

Comment: environment is set to Production mode.The device tokens which are stored in database from developer/ ad-Hoc or some of stored in after approving the app. Is this a problem??

Comment: Have you double check all device token set into database server side?

Comment: yes I did there are only 19 tokens but they all are mixed (developer/ ad-Hoc or production )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing similar kind of problem , issue is with your simplepush.php file.

I fixed it by opening and closing stream socket for each user. By doing this fixed my issue.

Sample code

```
foreach($iosUsers as $userDetails)
{
   // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195',$err,
                                $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
     exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

   // Build the binary notification
   $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $userDetails) . pack('n',strlen($payload)) . $payload;
  // Send it to the server
  $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
  if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
  else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

  fclose($fp);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

to

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

Comment: he got `access token` and able to send to server. so i think there is no any mistakes.

Comment: very Thanks for reply Sumit Garg but I've already coded for iOS 7< iOS 8+